# How to reload a page with parameters?

Tags: jquery

I want to reload a page with some parameters I uses this code-

```
 location.reload('https://makemyfoam.com/checkout#three');
```

but it reload the page on `https://makemyfoam.com/checkout`.

I use javascript code-

```
 window.location.href = window.location.href + "#three";
```

it only adds the `#three` in URL instead of loading the page.

but I want to reload the page on  `https://makemyfoam.com/checkout#three` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
const loc = window.location;
loc.href = loc.origin + loc.pathname + "#three";
loc.reload()
```

PS: please note using `location.origin+location.pathname+'#anchor'` instead of `location.href+'#anchor'` to avoid getting something like that:
`https://www.example.com/page#anchor1#anchor2#anchor3`